# Django Test Client sends values as a list instead of strings

Tags: django, django-testing

I have a problem, I am not sure whether I had overlooked something, or simply doing something wrong. I am trying to test an endpoint that allows a user to register.

My model:

```
class Account(User):
    objects = UserManager()
    balance = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0)
    rank_position = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    rank_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="Novice")
```

Serializer:

```
class AccountSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = '__all__
```

View:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def register(request):
    try:
        acc = Account.objects.create(**request.POST)
        acc_srl = AccountSerializer(acc)
        return Response(data=acc_srl.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And I am trying to use a Django test client in a following way:

```
class TestAuthentication(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()

    def test_register(self):
        data = {'username': 'test_user', 'password': '1234'}
        response = self.c.post('/api/register/', data)
        print(response.json())
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
        acc = Account.objects.get(username="test_user")
        self.assertEqual(acc.username, "test_user")
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(acc, User))
```

The function works as expected, but a strange thing happens. When I inspect `request.POST` both username and password are a list as so:

```
<QueryDict: {'username': ['test_user'], 'password': ['1234']}>
```

I am puzzled as I dont understand what causes this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function built-in to Django to handle multiple values with the same key. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict).

And when you are using Django's test client `this.c.post` and send data in the second parameter. Then Django will send that as URL parameters and not a POST body.

So your request will look like: `'/api/register/?username=test_user&password=1234'`

Let's say you send a request with `'/api/register/?username=test_user&password=1234&password=5486'`
Then your `request.POST` would look like:

```
<QueryDict: {'username': ['test_user'], 'password': ['1234', '5486']}>
```

So, I don't think you have to worry about this.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the normal behavior of the `request.POST`. As you can do a `POST` with multiple values for the same parameter: Eg: `/api/register/?username=user&username=admin`, so you will have

```py
<QueryDict: {'username': ['user', 'admin']}>
```

You can check this in the official doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Django's doc:

> In an HttpRequest object, the GET and POST attributes are instances of
> django.http.QueryDict, a dictionary-like class customized to deal with
> **multiple values** for the same key.

Then, if you want to access those items, use `QueryDict.__getitem__` method:

So, in your case, it would be something like:

```py
>>> request.POST['username']
test_user
>>> request.POST['password']
1234
```

Or if you have multiple values on the queryparams, you can use `QueryDict.getlist`:

```py
>>> POST = QueryDict('user_ids=ID1&user_ids=ID2&user_ids=ID3&')
>>> POST.getlist('user_ids')
['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3']
```

QueryDict: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

QueryDict.__getitem__: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.\_\_getitem\_\](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.%5C_%5C_getitem%5C_%5C)_

QueryDict.getlist: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist